# Followup: Show Data Gradually or All at Once

Tags: forms

This is a followup to my post a while ago which can be found [here](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/43245/show-data-gradually-or-all-at-once). I've made several suggested changes to my site and would like everybody to take a look here: http://bahcalculator.org/nano/.

I made the following improvements that the UX community suggested:

- Search field selected on startup
- Only showing information relative to the user
- Switched to the fantastic [UIKit](http://getuikit.com), which seems easier to use

Please let me know what you think of this new design and if there is something else I can improve upon to ensure the user experience is as good as it can be!

Answer (score 1):

*Looks* more modern but not sure *usability* is much better. For me it is like a calculator with huge gaps between keys. A lot of free space and borders for each block make interface a little scattered instead of logical grouping elements. But it's subjective feeling.

More objective remarks are:

- Top 1/3 of screen space is used non-efficiently. It is better to move the search form somewhere to Home menu level.
- `Search base` is more understandable label (gives instruction) than just `Search`.
- `Purchase details` button label is more consistent and more descriptive than `More Info`.
- There are some bugs, leading to strange results. An example is pictured. Test final version carefully. 
  [image]

What I really like are:

- Bigger font sizes.
- Detailed Monthly expenses table describes clearly montly payment.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. I changed the search title to "Search Location" and updated the more info button to "Purchase Details."

Comment: @caseym I think your customers will like compare functionality while looking for place, price comparing could be important, too.

Answer (score 1):

This is definitely better than what you had before, but there are still some possible improvements I believe.

It's really hard to tell what's the right design would be without knowing which is the primary user goal:

- Compare different locations.
- See the prices in a specific location (users are already assigned to a location).

Anyhow, you'll have to give some feedback on this task model I've drawn:

[image: Task model for comparing prices]

If the assumptions behind this task model are correct, then it strongly hints that users would prefer their choice to be serial.

So with this in mind:

- Grade and dependants choice should move next to the location/base choice.

And some additional comments:

- In the way 'Purchase Details' appears now, it is a fairly strong call for action. If isn't a business goal, I would suggest you replace it with a simply link.
- The home icon next to the purchase heading is:

  - inconsistent (no icon for the BAH rate).
  - not a great choice - BAH rate is also for a property, how does a house icon represents 'purchase'?
- Map:

  - With the task model above, the map only becomes relevant after the user chose location and base, satisfying the 'what's the area like?' variable.
  - If it is shown before the user has made a location choice, you may want to show all possible bases, and allow users select a base on the map. Otherwise, why is it there?
- Just a small thing to consider: I have chosen Delaware, for which there is only one base. I assume that in such case the system will automatically choose the only base available.